# How to disable wallpaper changes on Linux Mint 12?

Tags: linux-mint, desktop, desktop-customization

I'm looking for a way to disable the possibility of changing the wallpaper on a Linux Mint 12 install on a public computer. I searched the internet, but I didn't get any straightforward answer so far.

Answer (score 1):

This method worked in ubuntu. I've read Mint comes from ubuntu so I hope this works! (And I really hope it does, because it took me some investigating!)

You can use dconf. Dconf looks for the profile **user** to load its configurations, so you have  to create it if it isn't already (it wasn't for me).
You can also export a variable to set another default user but that'll be more hassle.

Go to /etc/dconf/profile and create a text file named **user**. This might require administrator rights.
The easiest way to do it is to open up a terminal (ctrl-alt-t) and writing this:

```
sudo gedit /etc/dconf/profile/user
```

Feel free to replace gedit by your favourite text editor (hint: vim)
When editing that file you should add the following line:

```
system-db:local
```

This tells dconf to open up the database local and load the settings for the system. You can name it poopman instead of local if you wish (if you do the same in the next steps).

**Now let's create the db file**. This goes in /etc/dconf/

First create the folder **local.d** and a subfolder **locks**

```
sudo mkdir -p local.d/locks
```

Inside, create the keyfile **00_wallpaper** and edit it. I believe you can name it chestnut if you wish but that's not going to be too descriptive.

```
sudo gedit /etc/dconf/db/local.d/locks/00_wallpaper
```

Add the following inside:

```
# prevent changes to the wallpaper
/org/gnome/desktop/background/picture-uri
```

Last step is to update system databases:

```
sudo dconf update
```

You should now see a file named local in /etc/dconf/db/

And voilà, no need to relog. Try to change your wallpaper right now and you'll see it's not possible!
To revert these changes just remove or comment the lock and run dconf update again.

Check this for more information: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/dconf/SystemAdministrators